# Connecting Remote Mysql to Netbeans

Tags: java, php, mysql, netbeans

Is it possible to connect a remote Mysql database to Netbeans?

I have seen many examples using a localhost database and it works just fine. I am working in a project which needs a remote database as it will retrieve information provided from a desktop computer to an apk.

I am currently working in the desktop part with netbeans but I cant connect it to the database.

```
enter code try {


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       conect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.webcindario.com/prosolve","username","password");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error "+e);
    }
    return conect;
```

This is where I make the connection and when i replaced the "mysql.webcindario.com" for localhost (when I tested it with a localhost db) worked fine.

[When I run the program it gets me this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qvu1.jpg)

I would apreciate your help and I apologize if im making a clear mistake, I am a student and I am not very expert but willing to learn. Thanks

Comment: To add to Mr. David's answer, also check firewall settings in both client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that your remote mysql service accept remote connexion by checking that you don't have a specific bind-adress set in your my.cnf and / or skip-networking is commented out in your configuration.

Also, even though it has nothing to do with your problem, you should probably avoid putting your DB login and password on a publicly available forum like stackoverflow as anybody would be able to access your data once you fix your problem :)